# Opentok interactive broadcasting integration in php

Tags: php, broadcast, opentok

I want to implement interactive broadcasting with OpenTok in a PHP application. What is a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok Developer Advocate here.

On the server side, you'll want to use our PHP SDK.  You can learn more about it, including  code samples, at https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/php/.

On the client side, you'll want to use OpenTok.js.  More information and sample code can be found at https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/.

In regards to interactive broadcasting, you can use the above libraries but the guide at https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/broadcast/ will help you setup the actual broadcast part of the application.

Comment: On the client side, you can check out https://github.com/opentok/opentok-web-samples.

On the server side, https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-PHP-SDK#samples has sample code in PHP.